# ssh Access denied from putty for raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I installed raspbian using NOOBS in raspberry pi 3 B+ . I enabled ssh in Pi .By typing ifconfig I obtained ip address .Using putty from windows I entered ip ,username and password I am getting access Denied in putty .I checked ip, username, password twice .From windows I was able to ping Pi(ping 192.168.1.33). but from Pi side ping is not working (ping 192.168.1.34 Windows ip). can anyone please suggest me the solution to ssh Pi. Thankyou in advanced

Comment: `I enabled ssh in Pi` how?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have enabled SSH?

You can check if SSH is running by running the following in a terminal

> sudo service ssh status

### Here are 3 methods to enable SSH

**Preferred method if running under Raspbian desktop**

> 1. Launch Raspberry Pi Configuration from the Preferences menu
> 2. Navigate to the Interfaces tab
> 3. Select Enabled next to SSH
> 4. Click OK

Using a terminal (IE: No desktop available)

> 1. Enter sudo raspi-config in a terminal window
> 2. Select Interfacing Options
> 3. Navigate to and select SSH
> 4. Choose Yes
> 5. Select Ok
> 6. Choose Finish

Alternatively, use systemctl to start the service if the above 2 options do not work, however I would really recommend the above 2 options, before this method.

> 1. sudo systemctl enable ssh
> 2. sudo systemctl start ssh